# busboy not firing field, file event

Tags: node.js, express, busboy

**In below code, only finish event called.**

---

```
var Busboy = require('connect-busboy');

app.use(Busboy());

app.post('/fileupload', function(req, res) {
  var fstream;

  req.pipe(req.busboy);

  req.busboy.on('error', function(err){
    console.log(err);
  });

  req.busboy.on('field', function(fieldname, val, valTruncated, keyTruncated) {
    console.log("fieldname: " + fieldname); 
  });

  req.busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename) {
    console.log("filename: " + filename); 
    fstream = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/files/' + filename);
    file.pipe(fstream);
    fstream.on('close', function () {
      res.redirect('back');
      console.log("fileupload end");
    });
  });

  req.busboy.on('finish', function() {
    console.log('Done parsing form!');
  });
});
```

Comment: What does `console.log(req.headers['content-type'])` output?

Comment: multipart/form-data;boundary=gc0p4Jq0M2Yt08jU534c0p

Comment: If you add `req.on('data', function(d) { console.log('Saw ' + d.length + ' request bytes') })` to your post route, do you see that output?

Comment: did not see any output

Comment: Ok that means that some other middleware before the code you've posted is reading all of the request data. Can you post the other middleware you're `app.use()`ing?

Comment: app.use(methodOverride());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(multer());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

Comment: remove "multer()" and got output Saw 64986 request bytes
Saw 33318 request bytes
Saw 65536 request bytes
Saw 10459 request bytes

Comment: but yet field and file event not execute

Comment: Try removing the data debugging line that you added.

Comment: req.on('data',.......removed but event not called

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why you're not seeing any data is because you're already using the `multer` module which also parses `multipart/form-data` requests, saving files to disk. If you're not using `multer` and want to use `busboy` manually as you show in your code, you will need to remove the `app.use(multer());` line.

Comment: yes its right. and get data but still field and file event not being called

Comment: Are you able to dump the raw request data and post it somewhere?

Comment: That data looks fine to me, assuming the line endings check out (they should be `\r\n`). If you can reproduce the problem with a minimal test case (e.g. `http.createServer()` and `busboy` only), please post the code somewhere so I can try it on my end.

Answer (score 0):

OK, late to the party.  But I had this issue and only found the solution via with the help of ChatGPT.

I wanted to keep with busboy specifically so I could stream the file and the only way to stream is it via the `file` event.

### My problem

I used a javascript upload using `FormData` `Request` & `Fetch`.  Plus my data was not an HTML `input='files'`.  I was creating the data from my application and saving it to a file.

None of this was a problem when I just set the request body to simply be the data.  It became a problem when I started using `multpart/form-data`.

### Solution

To enable the `busboy` `file` event you need to make sure the data has a filename associated with it.  That means you need to call the `.append` method with a filename argument.

```js
  const formData = new FormData();
  const fileName = 'myFileName.ext';
  formData.append('files', blobData, fileName);
```

Once I set the filename then my `busboy` `file` event fired properly, **Yay**!

#### Other note:

If you append a `filename` then `append` expects `blobData`.

Comment: [AI generated posts are not allowed.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy)

Comment: ChatGPT did not generate this post, I did.  ChatGPT helped me to uncover this, stackoverflow did not identify this specific issue, spent a long time searching.  I thought it was worth having this answer in the stackoverflow corpus.  Just trying to add to stackOverflow!

Comment: If you wrote the answer yourself, then what is the purpose of mentioning ChatGPT? It is like saying I Googled and figured out the solution. Serves no purpose whatsoever.